How to transform frequency table?
I am generating a frequency table with code table(data$col1, data$col2). col1 has Yes/No variables while col2 has count of U/R variables The resulting table has structure



Recd
Var
Freq




No
R
40


Yes
R
97


No
U
24


Yes
U
32



But instead I want it to be like



Recd
U
R




Yes
32
97


No
24
40



How should I write my code to have the resulting frequency table like shown?
Edit: I am looking for a code which will generate this format of frequency table from the data directly if possible and avoid reshaping of data later.

library(dplyr)  library(tidyr)  df %>%   arrange(desc(Var), desc(Recd)) %>%    pivot_wider(names_from = Var, values_from = Freq, values_fill = list(Freq = 0))

@Edward Thanks for the link. I was looking for a code/modification in the table() command itself which would do this. If it is not possible then I will use the external reshaping once I have generated the table.

Try reshape(X[with(X, order(Recd, Var, decreasing = TRUE)), ], idvar = "Recd", timevar = "Var", direction = "wide").
